# Ошибка "Could not determine Java version..." IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

Установил давно java 10 и IntelliJ IDEA, все прекрасно работало. В один день при открытии IntelliJ IDEA появилась ошибка

```
Could not determine Java version using executable C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10\bin\java.exe
```

Погуглил и понял что версия Gradle не подходит для этой версии Java. Что очень странно, раньше оно работало и я не помню чтобы я что-то менял. Но да ладно, устанавливаю Gradle 4.9 так как сказано на [официальном сайте](https://gradle.org/install/#manually). (Скачал архив, кинул в корень диска С, поправил переменные среды, проверил в консоли версию - все работает).

Открываю IntelliJ IDEA, создаю новый проект - ошибка не исчезла. В настройках проверил - версия Gradle стоит та, что нужно. Подскажите что делать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

В общем после перезагрузки ПК все заработало. Так что самое простое решение этой ошибки как по мне:

1. [вот здесь](https://gradle.org/install/#manually) выполнить шаги 1-4 для установки Gradle
2. перезагрузить ПК.
3. В Intelij Idea  ***File->Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Gradle*** в графе ***'use local gradle distribution'*** указать путь к распакованному архиву.